# What is the difference between the read.csv and read_csv function in R when working with NULL values?

Tags: r, null, readr

I am having an issue in R when uploading my csv file. For some reason, when using the read.csv function, my null values were not showing up as null after saving the csv file to a data frame. Does anyone know why the read.csv function is not showing null values but the read_csv function preserves the null values. NOTE: I'm a beginner and have been working with large datasets and R for about 5 weeks.

Using `read.csv`:

```
#Importing my csv file
(jan_data <- read.csv('202301-divvy-tripdata.csv'))

# Check for NULL values in the entire data frame
missing_values_df <- is.na(jan_data)

# Print the logical matrix indicating NULL values
print(missing_values_df)

# Count the number of NULL values in each column
print(colSums(missing_values_df))
```

The output:

```
ride_id      rideable_type         started_at           ended_at start_station_name 
                 0                  0                  0                  0                  0 
  start_station_id   end_station_name     end_station_id          start_lat          start_lng 
                 0                  0                  0                  0                  0 
           end_lat            end_lng      member_casual 
               127                127                  0
```

Using `readr::read_csv()`:

````
jan_data <- read_csv('202301-divvy-tripdata.csv')

#Check for NULL values in the entire data frame
missing_values_df <- is.na(jan_data)

#Print the logical matrix indicating NULL values
print(missing_values_df)

#Count the number of NULL values in each column
print(colSums(missing_values_df))```
````

Output:

```
ride_id      rideable_type         started_at           ended_at start_station_name 
                 0                  0                  0                  0              26721 
  start_station_id   end_station_name     end_station_id          start_lat          start_lng 
             26721              27840              27840                  0                  0 
           end_lat            end_lng      member_casual 
               127                127                  0
```

Comment: How may rows are in the data? What types of values are in each column? If you run `sapply(jan_data, class)` for both methods, do they have the same data types? Also note the "NULL" and "NA" are two different things in R. You use "NA" for missing values in vectors, not NULL. It's really hard to help without some sort of reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 190,000 rows of data. When using **read_csv**, this is the output of **sapply()** : $start_station_id [1] "character" . When using read.csv, this is the output: start_station_name "character".  It seems like they are the same data type but print out differently when using the function.

Comment: I'm guessing that writing `NULL` to a CSV-format file involves some backslashes.  Do you see those in your CSVs?

Answer (score 4):

The difference in *character columns* when using the default `na.strings=` argument in `read.csv` and `na=` argument in `read_csv` is in empty fields.  Try the code below where the second field on the last row is empty.

The reason for the difference is that by default `na.strings="NA"` in `read.csv` so empty fields result in zero length strings whereas in `read_csv` the default is `na=c("", "NA")` so empty fields result in an `NA` (not a NULL).

```
cat("A,B,C\na,b,c\nd,,e\n", file = "test.csv")
readr::read_csv("test.csv")
## ... snip ...
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     c    
2 d     <NA>  e

read.csv("test.csv")
##   A B C
## 1 a b c
## 2 d   e
```

Comment: It should be noted that we can use `read.csv("test.csv", na.strings=c(NA, ''))` to read the data without using a package for this simple task.